# How to Auto-Trigger Jenkins Pipeline in Different Repository upon Push to common infra repository?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have set up a Jenkins pipeline in a repository called infra-repo, where all configurations related to deployments and Kubernetes files are stored. However, my actual project resides in a different repository. The Jenkins pipeline script is located in infra-repo/project-repo-name/pipeline/dev/Jenkins and contains the code for the pipeline.

The pipeline script essentially clones the repository mentioned in the Jenkinsfile, builds an image, pushes the image to the artifact repository, and then deploys Kubernetes deployments using the image URL.

I would like to automate the triggering of this Jenkins pipeline whenever a push occurs in the project repository. The Git SCM is configured for infra-repo, but I want the trigger to be activated when any push occurs in the project repository.

What configuration changes or additional steps are required to achieve this auto-triggering mechanism? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Cross-Repository Trigger: I want the project pipeline to be triggered automatically whenever there's a new push to the project repository, even though the Jenkins pipeline script resides in the infra-repo.